# Is it possible to export all schemas in a database with oracle data pump?

Tags: database, oracle, datapump

I am using Oracle 11g 11.2.0.1.0 and I'm trying to find a way of using data pump to export ALL schemas in a database. I know you can specify multiple schemas using the SCHEMAS argument, but I need to be able to export all schemas without having to explicitly name them, because at any given time I don't know exactly what schemas are there (it's a development database and developers can add schemas whenever they want). Is there a way to do this with data pump? Or is there some other tool which could do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can export all schemas with `full=y`:

```
expdp system/password@db10g full=Y directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=DB10G.dmp logfile=expdpDB10G.log
impdp system/password@db10g full=Y directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=DB10G.dmp logfile=impdpDB10G.log
```

[source](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php)

Comment: Just a caution with Oracle 12c, be sure to not use the `SYS` user, or `SYSDBA` role when doing a `full=y` and be aware that DataPump will not export Oracle-maintained tables such as APEX, etc.